# PDFTronPHP install segfault

Tags: php, pdftron

I try to install PDFTron on PHP.

I followed the documentation on https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/php/get-started/integration/linux/#initial-setup

But I have a segfault when I run php

```
bash-5.1# php
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I write and Dockerfile to reproduce error :

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
# persistent / runtime deps
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        make \
        bash \
        git \
        gcc \
        swig \
        cmake \
        gcompat \
        $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    ;

# Install PDFTron
WORKDIR /var/www

RUN git clone https://github.com/PDFTron/PDFNetWrappers # Git clone the code.
# Move to where we download PDFNet.
WORKDIR /var/www/PDFNetWrappers/PDFNetC
RUN wget http://www.pdftron.com/downloads/PDFNetC64.tar.gz # Download PDFNet.
RUN tar xzvf PDFNetC64.tar.gz # Unpack PDFNet.
RUN mv PDFNetC64/Headers/ . # Move PDFNet Headers/ into place.
RUN mv PDFNetC64/Lib/ . # Move PDFNet Lib/ into place.

# Go back up /PDFNetWrappers.
WORKDIR /var/www/PDFNetWrappers

RUN mkdir Build # Create a directory to create the Makefiles in.
#  Move to that directory.
WORKDIR /var/www/PDFNetWrappers/Build
#RUN apt-get install php-dev # add php-dev for required PHP include directories
RUN cmake -D BUILD_PDFNetPHP=ON /var/www/PDFNetWrappers # Create the Makefiles with CMake.
RUN make # Build the PHP wrappers with SWIG.
RUN make install # Copy the PHP wrappers to where the samples can find them.
```

Does anyone has the segfault after installation. How can I fix this seg fault

Comment: "FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine" Are you trying to run on Alpine distro? If so, Alpine is not supported. Normally users use Debian instead, though there are many other distro you can use (e.g. CentOS, Ubuntu, REHL) just not a MUSL based one.

Comment: Yes i try to run on alpine since it's the distro I have for my PHP project. i did not see anywhere that alpine was not maintenaid